# Where to find plastic corner pipe cover

Tags: walls, pipe, pvc, cover

I'm looking for a plastic box with 2 open sides that can be attached to the wall. Maybe about 8x8 or 10x10. I need to cover a PVC vent pipe that curves in the corner of the wall.  I just can't find it.  I can imagine how it should look but have not found anything like it yet.  I don't want to box it in with 2x2s and drywall since it's so small and studs aren't in the right place so I'd have to make the box like 23 x 14 inches instead. A little plastic box cover would be so much easier and simpler.  Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a lot of options with this one, since it's just peeking from the corner and not running along the wall (if the elbow were the opposite direction). If I were covering this, I would use some decorative wood and build 4 sides of a box on the top, bottom, and 2 faces of this PVC. It ends up looking something like this: https://www.wikihow.com/images/thumb/2/27/Hide-Pipes-in-the-Kitchen-Step-14.jpg/aid5958328-v4-728px-Hide-Pipes-in-the-Kitchen-Step-14.jpg
You could attach such a box to the wall with glue, or a hinge if you periodically need access to it (e.g. to check for leaks).

If you want to be less formal (this looks like a basement, so maybe the industrial look is OK or desired, even) they make pretty sturdy plastic boxes with squared sides, you could cut two sides off of one of these to hide your PVC. My favorite look is the Project Box (https://www.google.com/search?q=project+box) and these come in many shapes, sizes and colors and most feature a screwplate lid so you could still have access to the PVC inside.

Comment: Yea I guess I will probably go with your first option and just get a piece of thin wood or MDF board and assemble a box and then glue it to the wall. I'm really surprised that there isn't a plastic box specifically made for the corners.